# Flash File with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, flash

Can anyone let me know why the flash file appearing on this page http://dev5.99medialabtest2.com/carwash/window-tinting/ (just above the Our Location section) is not appearing?

Comment: Check your flash file path it showing 404 error : http://dev5.99medialabtest2.com/carwash/window-tinting/Simulator_Flash_Auto.swf. See in browser console.

Comment: what the code you did on this page that can help us to give you a perfect solution for same

Comment: flash file display how to tools used ?

Comment: Live demo link

(http://tarang.tk/flash-file.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

embed tag code replace this code

```
<embed width="800" height="600" src="http://www.autosmartnetwork.com/automotive-window-film-simulator/Simulator_Flash_Auto.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" align="middle" play="true" loop="true" scale="showall" wmode="window" devicefont="false" bgcolor="#ffffff" name="Simulator_Flash_Auto" menu="true" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" salign="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Comment: How did you reach to this link http://www.autosmartnetwork.com/automotive-window-film-simulator/Simulator_Flash_Auto.swf ?

Comment: @Hemant is it working? code I gave you in answer. and i got that link from google search. please accept answer if it's working.

Comment: No, it's not working for me. I have added that code. Please check.

Comment: @Hemant you have a correct answer here. Make sure you use the code correctly in your own html file. What browse did you test with (it must understand HTML5)? You say _"Please check."_ but cannot provide line number (in code) where used the `embed` tag? Use it just normal like `<image>` or <video> tag. Try a basic <embed> without extra crap like `<noscript>`